# Can TextMate find matching opening and closing tags?

Tags: ide, textmate

Something I liked in Visual Studio was that I could click an opening tag, say  and it would do its best to highlight in bold the closing tag.  Does anyone know if you can do that in textmate?  I searched an looked but cannot find it.

It gets hard to find the closing tag many DIVs deep.

If TextMate won't do it, can anyone tell me an editor on Mac that will?

Thank you for any help.

EDIT: If it can do it, can someone please tell me how?  Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Install the experimental bundle - and look for the "Select Balanced Tags" macro (Shift-Command-B)

Comment: This has been added directly to Textmate, no need for a bundle. Shortcut key is the same, or `Edit` ->  `Select` -> `Enclosing Typing Pairs`.

Comment: @GrahamPHeath Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you transverse with your keyboard or mouse the closing tag, TM will flash you the opening one.

But I think the reverse it's not possible (or at least, haven't found a way to work it like that)